# Starting a yakuake session with specified profile using dbus?

Tags: session, dbus, konsole, yakuake

How can I launch a yakuake session with a specific profile? Unlike org.kde.konsole.Window's newSession method, the addSession method of org.kde.yakuake /yakuake/sessions doesn't take any arguments and thus doesn't let me specify a profile name. How can I circumvent this?

Answer (score 0):

```
$ qdbus org.kde.yakuake /yakuake/sessions org.kde.yakuake.addSession
$ qdbus org.kde.yakuake /Windows/1 org.kde.konsole.Window.newSession 'profile' '.'
```

Of course, the Window number may be different.

Answer (score 0):

The following works for me

```bash
➜ read session_id < <(qdbus org.kde.yakuake /yakuake/sessions org.kde.yakuake.addSession)
➜ qdbus org.kde.yakuake /Sessions/$((session_id + 1)) org.kde.konsole.Session.setProfile <profile_name>
```